# Accessing variable names dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have the following scenario:

```
if (event.status == AMFResultEvent.SUCCESS) {                
var lev1:uint = 0;
var lev2:uint = 0;
var lev3:uint = 0;
var lev4:uint = 0;
var lev5:uint = 0;
var lev6:uint = 0;

for (var i:int = 0; i < event.result.length; i++) {
    if (mainLevel == "1") {
        lev1++;
    }
    if (mainLevel == "2") {
        lev2++;
    }
    if (mainLevel == "3") {
        lev3++;
    }
    if (mainLevel == "4") {
        lev4++;
    }
    if (mainLevel == "5") {
        lev5++;
    }
    if (mainLevel == "6") {
        lev6++;                        
    }
}

for (var j:int = 1; j < 7; j++) {                
    _row = new StatisticsRow(event.result[j], this);
    _rowsPlace.addChild(_row);
    _row.y = (_row.height +1) * j;
    _row.codeLevel.htmlText = j; // works as it should
    // need to access variables lev1 - lev6, called by something like "lev"+j here:
    _row.amount.htmlText = 
}

// traces correct amounts of mainLevels from the i loop:
trace ("level 1: " + lev1);
trace ("level 2: " + lev2);
trace ("level 3: " + lev3);
trace ("level 4: " + lev4);
trace ("level 5: " + lev5);
trace ("level 6: " + lev6);
```

}

I'm missing something obvious here, as the ["lev"]+j doen't work. How can I dynamically acces the lev1 - lev6 in the j-loop? As the code comment at the bottoms shows, this traces as expected.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can access them with brackets, string concatenation, and the `this` keyword. Here's an example of how you would use bracket notation in a loop:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    var currLev = this["lev"+i];
    // do stuff to currLev
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I apologize for my shortcomings on this topic, but I can't make it work. Firstly, should the var currLev be typed? And secondly, if I use the this keyword, I get Error #1069: Property lev1 not found on ClassName. I need to reference the variables in created at the top, by somehow adding the j in the j-loop.

Comment: Try to make your class 'dynamic'.

Comment: It is a pretty huge class, so I'd rather not change anything about the class it self, if I don't have to. Is there no way to reference the variables already created by manipulating the number in the variable name?

If I write `_row.amount.htmlText = lev1;` that line parses as it should, but of course assigns the lev1 value to all rows. So I just need to alter the number in the end of the variable by assigning j from the j-loop. I assume the problem is syntax?

Comment: `this` needs to be a reference to the class with the lev* variables. If this loop is outside of that class, then you replace that with a variable name: `ClassName c = new ClassName(); for (var i:int = 0; i <=6; i++) { trace(c["lev"+i]); }`

Comment: Everything is in the same class, in the same function. I just didn't include the rest of the function above, my bad. The i-loop is just above the j-loop.

Comment: Don't just copy my code. It's not exact for your situation, I was trying to explain the concept you needed to use (which is the `this["lev"+i]` notation). You can put that in your j loop and replace i with j and you'll have a reference to lev(j). I'll edit my answer to say it's not a specific solution to your problem, but more an example for bracket notation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping!
I get that, and it's what I tried at first. However when doing that, `this["lev"+i];` gives error:
"ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property lev1 not found on "package.ClassName" and there is no default value."

If I use only `code ["lev"+i]; `code all the row's textfields are poplulated with the string variable name lev*, not the value of lev* already created.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering guys!

I had a lousy approach to my problem anyway, and should have used an array right away:

```
var mainLevels:Array = new Array();

for (var n:int = 1; n < 7; n++) {
    mainLevels[n] = 0;
}

if (event.status == AMFResultEvent.SUCCESS) {

    for (var i:int = 0; i < event.result.length; i++) {

        var data = event.result[i];
        var correctCode:String = data["correct"];
        var mainLevelFound:uint = uint(correctCode.substr(0, 1));

        for (var k:int = 1; k < 7; k++) {
            if (k == mainLevelFound) {
                mainLevels[k]++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (var j:int = 1; j < 7; j++) {

    _row = new StatisticsRow(event.result[j], this);
    _rowsPlace.addChild(_row);
    _row.y = (_row.height +1) * j;
    _row.codeLevel.htmlText = j;
    // Now this works as a reference to mainLevels[*] created above!
    _row.amount.htmlText = mainLevels[j];
}
```

Thanks again for your effort :)